# Replacing a pair of characters in a string with another

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, replace, c-strings

I want to replace a pair of characters with another pair.

For example if want to replace "ax" with "57" and the string is "vksax", it will give out "vks57".

Tried it this way but get a weird output that is only partially correct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   
char dummy;
int i;
char string[16];
scanf("%s", string);

for(i=0;string[i];i++){
  if(string[i] == 'a'  && string[i+1] == 'x'){
    string[i] = '5' ;
    string[i+1] = '7';
    i=0;  
  }
printf("%s", string) ;
}
   exit(0);
}
```

I can't figure out why it gives, for example, with an input of `1234ax` the output `1234ax1234ax1234ax1234ax123457123457123457123457123457123457`

Comment: Also plese format your code properly, for example like the samples in your learning material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the for loop

```
for(i=0;string[i];i++){
  if(string[i] == 'a'  && string[i+1] == 'x'){
    string[i] = '5' ;
    string[i+1] = '7';
    i=0;  
  }
```

this statement

```
i=0;
```

does not make a sense. Remove it. And instead of

```
    string[i+1] = '7';
```

write

```
    string[++i] = '7';
```

And move this call

```
printf("%s", string) ;
```

outside the for loop.

Pay attention to that the variable `dummy` is declared but not used.

```
char dummy;
```

Remove this declaration.

And there is no great sense to use `exit( 0 );` instead of `return 0;`.

And the call of `scanf` will be more safer if to write it like

```
scanf("%15s", string);
```

Comment: Ty , i didnt realise the printf is in the for loop!

Comment: @TobiKanovi that's what programming is. trying and finding a solution

Comment: @TobiKanovi See my appended answer.

Comment: @TobiKanovi i think you didn't realize that the `printf` is in the loop because of your indentation style (or lack thereof). [Here's your code with consistent indentation](https://godbolt.org/z/hencr4aaM) - See how obvious it is that the `printf` is within the loop?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah its a lot more obvious there , il  work on my indentation style xD cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is marked as C++, here is C++ one-line answer:

```
#include <string>
std::string String = "vksax";
String.replace(String.find("ax"), 2, "57");
```

Get yourself familiar with std::string
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Solution as function(it assumes substring to be replaced and replacement have the same length):

```
std::string FindAndReplace(std::string sInputString, std::string sReplaceThis, std::string sReplacement)
{
    size_t iPos = sInputString.find(sReplaceThis);
    if(iPos == std::string::npos)
        return sInputString;

    sInputString.replace(iPos, sReplacement.length(), sReplacement);
    return sInputString;
};
```